# Алгоритм взаимодействия с Google Maps API

Tags: google-maps-api, google-maps

При работе с Google Maps API возникли некоторые сложности.
Задача: нужно искать по карте адреса и места (магазины, McDonald’s и прочие), причём поиск производится через одну строку поиска, как через google.com. Также нужна возможность определения местоположения, если есть такая необходимость.

Проблема в том, что я не знаю, что именно пользователь ищет: точный адрес, или какое место. Соответственно, если это место без указания местоположения (просто "ресторан", а не "ресторан Москва"), то узнаём местоположение, и опираемся на него при поиске. Если же ищется адрес, или место с указанием города или области, то не определяем местоположение. И я не могу вот это разделить: в API есть какие-то категории результатов, но я не пойму, как ими пользоваться в моём случае.

Заранее благодарю за ответы.

Comment: В документации по геокодированию в АПИ Гугля все расписано. Что конкретно не получается?.. Покажите код, какие ошибки?..

Comment: Я не знаю как сделать. Код мне не нужен, нужен тока алгорити. Сначала я делаю запрос к геокодеру, и как мне оттуда узнать что написал пользователь, указал ли он город или область, да в гугле есть параметры в ответе types, но там нет таких понятий как город или область или что то в этом роде.